# The player in my code is not stopping. Can anyone tell if there is any error in this code?

Tags: python, pygame

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        playerX_change = -0.1
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        playerX_change = 0.1
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0
```

if have tried changing many things but the solution doesn't come
I actually got this code from a tutorial here's the link of it and the timestamp of it
https://youtu.be/FfWpgLFMI7w?t=2907
it is working in the video but not for me

Comment: Hm. Is the identation here exactly as in your code? It might be because your "if event.type == pygame.KEYUP is too indented and is treated as a case after left and right. 
I would say this should be on the top level, i.e. parallel to keydown.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You need to evaluate the event type in the event loop:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            playerX_change = -0.1
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0.1

    # INDENTATION
    #<--|
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0
```